# How to add N entries to json{b}_build_object where N is number of rows in table?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Given this table setup:

```
create table accounts (
    id char(4) primary key,
    first_name varchar not null
);

create table roles (
    account_id char(4) references accounts not null,
    role_type varchar not null,
    role varchar not null,

    primary key (account_id, role_type)
);
```

and initial account insertion:

```
insert into accounts (id, first_name) values ('abcd', 'Bob');
```

I want to get all the account info of someone, along w/ the roles they have as key-value pairs. Using a join for this one-to-many relationship would duplicate the account information across each row containing the role, so I want to create a JSON object instead. Using this query:

```
select
    first_name,
    coalesce(
        (select jsonb_build_object(role_type, role) from roles where account_id = id), 
        '{}'::jsonb
    ) as roles
from accounts where id = 'abcd';
```

I get this expected result:

```
 first_name | roles 
------------+-------
 Bob        | {}
(1 row)
```

After adding a first role:

```
insert into roles (account_id, role_type, role) values ('abcd', 'my_role_type', 'my_role');
```

I get another expected result:

```
 first_name |            roles            
------------+-----------------------------
 Bob        | {"my_role_type": "my_role"}
(1 row)
```

But after adding a second role:

```
insert into roles (account_id, role_type, role) values ('abcd', 'my_other_role_type', 'my_other_role');
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

**How do I replace this error with**

```
 first_name |            roles            
------------+-----------------------------
 Bob        | {"my_role_type": "my_role", "my_other_role_type": "my_other_role"}
(1 row)
```

**?**

I'm on Postgres v13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `json_object` and `array_agg` with a group by to achieve this outcome. See example with working fiddle below:

**Query #1**

```
select
    a.first_name,
    json_object(
         array_agg(role_type),
         array_agg(role)
    )
from accounts a
inner join roles r on r.account_id = a.id
where a.id = 'abcd'
group by a.first_name;
```

| first_name | json_object |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | {"my_role_type":"my_role","my_other_role_type":"my_other_role"} |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oEiBs5MJrLogMSTxSNaraH/0)

#### Edit 1:

The following modification using a left join and case expression to provide an alternative for results containing null values:

```sql
select
    a.first_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(role_type)=0 THEN '{}'::json
        ELSE
            json_object(
                array_agg(role_type),
                array_agg(role)
            )
    END as role
from accounts a
left join roles r on r.account_id = a.id
group by a.first_name;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oEiBs5MJrLogMSTxSNaraH/1)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks ggordon, this has been working great so far. But because `a.id` is a primary key, `r.account_id = a.id` would leave only one account remaining. Since there is only a single account during the join, why do I have to keep the group by around? Postgres says each select column must appear in there, but there is only ever one account per the filter.

Comment: the group by facilitates the `array_agg` function in this example which is an aggregate function. You could remove the group by, but then the firstname or other non aggregate columns would need to be in an aggregate  as well. I have used the max function in this [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oEiBs5MJrLogMSTxSNaraH/2) to demonstrate.